# convert python3.5 codes to exe file using pyinstaller warnout missing module

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm converting my python 3.5 program to an exe file using pyinstaller ,here's my environment: 
system:windows 10
python:python 3.5,exactly i installed Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
pyinstaller:3.2
I have already copy myfile.py in pyinstall file

then i run in cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts
pyinstaller.exe -F myfile.py
```

The code runs successfuly,and I got 2 folder

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\build
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\dist
```

In "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\dist" , I got a myfile.exe , bug when I run it , the error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line  11, in <module>
   File "c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
   exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
   File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
   File "site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 61, in load_module
ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution.
Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

I checked the logs in C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\build\myfile\warnout.txt , then got warns like this:

```
missing module named PyQt5.QtCore.QCoreApplication - imported by PyQt5.QtCore, c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py
missing module named PyQt5.QtCore.QIODevice - imported by PyQt5.QtCore
missing module named PyQt5.QtCore.QBuffer - imported by PyQt5.QtCore
missing module named PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap - imported by PyQt5.QtGui
missing module named PyQt5.QtGui.QImage - imported by PyQt5.QtGui
missing module named PyQt5.QtGui.qRgba - imported by PyQt5.QtGui
missing module named 'PyQt5.sip' - imported by c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py
missing module named numpy.infty - imported by numpy, scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve.lsmr
missing module named numpy.finfo - imported by numpy, scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve.minres, scipy.optimize.slsqp, scipy.optimize.minpack, scipy.optimize.zeros
missing module named numpy.inner - imported by numpy, scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve.minres
missing module named pandas.core.base.NoNewAttributesMixin - imported by pandas.core.base, pandas.core.strings, pandas.tseries.common, pandas.core.categorical
missing module named pandas.core.base.PandasDelegate - imported by pandas.core.base, pandas.tseries.common, pandas.core.categorical
missing module named pandas.core.base.AccessorProperty - imported by pandas.core.base, pandas.core.strings
```

There's many warns like this , I also tried some similar codes like:

```
pyinstaller.exe -F "myfile.py"
pyinstaller.exe --onefile "myfile.py"
pyinstaller.exe -F -p C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas myfile.py   #(-p options like this)
```

But I got the same result also(no error occured,but warns happened,and the exe file can't use)

How can I do ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have solved it , just do like this:

first install pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

because if install pyinstaller with pyinstaller.exe , you may short of some dependents package . then

```
pip unistall pyinstaller
```

yes , you just do it . 
then , download the pyinstaller developed version from

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller

then , unpack the zip file , run cmd in the file,

```
python setup.py install
```

That's ok ......